Adding init .sh file for databricks job
I have a python script that's using a cluster that has an init script:
 /Volumes/projects/default/admin/odbc.sh

this helps me connect via odbc to a sql server table.
When I run the job and add the cluster that has this ^ I see the error I saw before adding this to my cluster which was:

Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found

My question is, how to add this .sh file to my job??

If your primary req. is to connect to SQL Server please try this preferred method
https://docs.databricks.com/en/connect/external-systems/sql-server.html

I have tried the below approach:
The below code downloads the install MS SQL ODBC Driver on Azure Databricks cluster.
First Approach:
%sh
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get -q -y install msodbcsql17

Second Approach:
if ! [[ "18.04 20.04 22.04 23.04 24.04" == *"$(lsb_release -rs)"* ]];
then
    echo "Ubuntu $(lsb_release -rs) is not currently supported.";
    exit;
fi

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/prod.list | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
#optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools18
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools18/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
#optional: for unixODBC development headers
sudo apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev

Results:


Reference:

SO link
Install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server
(Linux)

